# Filtro de arquivo Bash

Tags: bash

Estou querendo imprimir colunas específicas de um arquivo. Meu arquivo está assim:

```
                                                   random    random
   kB  reclen    write  rewrite    read    reread    read     write
10240    4096    35383    32281    58250   130504   100674    38425
```

Tem mais colunas..

```
bkwd    record    stride                                    
read   rewrite      read   fwrite frewrite    fread  freread
```

O que eu quero é imprimir as colunas kB, reclen, write, read, random read e random write, apenas.

O meu código está assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..15}; do
  iozone -i 0 -i 1 -i 2 -I -s 10M -r 4096 -w -e |tee dataiozone$i.txt
  sed -n '28,30p' dataiozone$i.txt > filter$i.txt
  rm dataiozone$i.txt
done

    grep -v iozone * | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7}' > out.txt
```

O grep eu já testei, está realmente pegando todas as linhas de todos os arquivos, o único equivoco que estou cometendo deve ser no awk.

Comment: Qua o erro ocorre ? utilizei aqui grep -v iozone a | awk  -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7}' e funcionou. Adicionei o tab como separador para ficar mais legível a saída

Comment: `grep ... * ` apanha linhas de todos os ficheiros existentes na pasta talve mais prudente seria `grep -v iozone filter*.txt | ...` .Ficava mais simples `iozone ... | sed ...> filter...txt`.  Que rro dá ao certo?